# Blur() event doesn't work for me

Tags: events, jquery, blur, onblur

This is my jQuery code:

```
$('input[name="Search"]').blur(function(e) {
    $(this).text('');
});
```

And my HTML snippet:

```
<input name="Search" type="text" id="Search" class="MainMenu" />
```

But it doesn't work, does anybody know why?

Comment: I did not down vote, but showing html will help to sort the problem

Comment: You want to blank text of search box on blur?

Comment: yes @Harry, that's what I want

Comment: Try val instead of text as per @Pragnesh chauhan answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `text()` on input type `text which is not defined for input type=text`. You need to use `val()`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/V4AFe/2/)**

```
$('input[name="Search"]').blur(function(e) { 
 $(this).val('');
});​
```

If you have id, you can **use id as it will be more efficient** then getting element with name selector.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/V4AFe/)**

```
$('#Search').blur(function(e) { 
    $(this).val('');
});​
```

Answer (score 3):

try `.val()` insteadof `.text()`

```
$('input[name="Search"]').blur(function(e) { 
 $(this).val('');
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no method like `.text()` for input type text use `.val()`

these change will help you

```
$('input[name="Search"]').blur(function(e) {
    $(this).val('');
});
```

or

```
$('#Search').blur(function(e) { 
    $(this).val('');
});​
```

[Documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/val/)